# Receiving a Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes error

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy

I understand that for Jenkins, it requires that all variables need to be serialized, but I am running into an issue and I do not understand why. I'm fairly new to Groovy/ Jenkins. Here is my code

```
@NonCPS
String myFunction(){
def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parse("${workspace}/tmp/TESTS-myTest.xml")
println "${parsed} is this"
//def errorMessage = parsed.testsuite.testcase.error.@message
//def testCases = parsed.testsuite.testcase

    println "We found 0 errors"

    parsed.testsuite.testcase.each { def device ->
    msgToSlack= "Name of phone is: ${device.@name}" + " " + "ran for ${((device.@time.toInteger())/60)} Minutes"
    println msgToSlack

    //"View at ${device}" 
    //println device.error.@message
}      
    return msgToSlack.toString()
}
```

What I am doing in this function is parsing an XML file that I get after curling to an API and receiving the results via webhook. Then I want to parse the document to get certain values to send via slack, this function runes fine but when I call the function I get a

````
    in field groovy.lang.GString.values
    in object org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl@684e4781
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@66757440
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@16a73957
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@16a73957
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes```

Any information leading me to the right direction would help! Thanks so much.
````

Comment: you have to read about @NonCPS.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/

Comment: Hey! I just read@NonCPS, my editor wasn't formatted correctly so that was cut off

Comment: declare somewhere the variable msgToSlack